# Using jQuery to create an accordion of provided content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really know JS / jQuery. I need to take this HTML and use JS to convert / re-structure it so it functions as an accordion.

HTML:

```
<h6>heading 1</h6>
<p>this is some content</p>
<p>this is some more content</p>

<h6>heading 2</h6>
<p>this is some content</p>
<p>this is some more content</p>

<h6>heading 3</h6>
<p>this is some content</p>
<p>this is some more content</p>
```

I need to take the h6 as the accordion link and content between for the content area. I managed to get this together from a tutorial but it does it as tabs and not sure how to redo so it acts / structures as an accordion:

I guess would need to be something like (when clicking on title changes to right content of course):

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="title">title 1</div>
  <div class="content">content 1</div>

  <div class="title">title 2</div>
  <div class="content">content 2</div>
</div>
```

JS that I need to adjust:

```
var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

  $('#tab_description h6').each(function(i){      
    $(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="tab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
  });

  for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ) {
    $('.tabs').append('<li class=""><a href="#tab-'+i+'">'+headers[i].innerHTML+'</a></li>');
  }

  $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
    var listitem = $(this).find('li');
    active = listitem.first().addClass('active');
    content = $(active.attr('href'));
      $('.tab').hide();
    $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
      $('.tab').hide();
      $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
      content.hide();
      active = $(this);
      content = $($(this).attr('href'));
      active.parent().addClass('active');
      content.show();
      return false;
    });
  });

  headers.remove(); // remove headers from description  
  $('#tab-0').show(); // show the first tab
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: IMO I think this is the type of thing one should actually write on their own. Its almost to simple to mess up. I mean... who hasnt written their own accordion when starting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple implementation of an accordion based on your structure. Codepen for it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZgMy

This implementation is using the jQuery `nextUntil` function to achieve the desired result.

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">

  <h6>heading 1</h6>
  <p>this is some content</p>
  <p>this is some more content</p>

  <h6>heading 2</h6>
  <p>this is some content</p>
  <p>this is some more content</p>

  <h6>heading 3</h6>
  <p>this is some content</p>
  <p>this is some more content</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion h6 {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion p {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
}

.accordion * {
  display: none
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.accordion h6').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('h6').toggle();
});
```

If you are wanting animations you could use jQuery to instead toggle a class on the paragraph items.

**Update - additional accordion functionality**

Here is an update to force only a single accordion to be opened at one time:
Updated Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyREYM

jQuery

```
var accordionContent = $('.accordion p');

$('.accordion h6').click(function() {

  // Check if current accordion item is open
  var isOpen = $(this).next().is(":visible");

  // Hide all accordion items
  accordionContent.hide();

  // Open accordion item if previously closed
  if (!isOpen) {
    $(this).nextUntil('h6').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thing is, i need to generate the source as its coming from shopify CMS so the structure is <h6>title</h6> content <h6>title</h6> content etc.. so need to take the h6 as the title and the content between as content... is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, really appreciate it! but yea need to use that HTML example i supplied and re-create based from that... thanks again mate!

Comment: Are you able to wrap the content in a div? This would make for a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: yep i can wrap it in a div, that is not a problem.

Comment: Can you wrap each accordion set in a div? like:
<div class="accordion">
  <h6>heading 1</h6>
    <p>this is some content</p>
    <p>this is some more content</p></div>

Comment: I can wrap it all that is returned..... but the h6, content, h6 content, h6 content... is returned by {{ product.description }} so i can only add a main wrapper around that.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I have modified the solution to match your exact html structure. I have also updated the Codepen link. Cheers

Comment: Thanks mate, codepen looks good, im going to integrate and test it out now! is it possible to close the one that is open is clicked on other? its only its for mobile so guess makes sense and not having to scroll down to click on the other one... thanks again mate! im just trying what it is currently anyway!

Comment: Check the update in the post. I added the modified jQuery which will prevent multiple accordion items being opened at any one time.

Comment: cool cheers mate, i had to add div, iframe and ul to the display none in the css as those were not hiding but other than that worked a charm! let me add this updated JS and many thanks again mate!!

Comment: oh i noticed accordion content targetting p element, would i just add the others that mentioned above in the call?

Comment: Just update the CSS to hide all elements by default. See the updated answer above.

Comment: Yep that is what i done, seems to work a treat! need to add some extra little bits to the JS but i think ive got it from here! thanks for all your help mate!

Comment: No worries. Good luck!

Comment: sorry to be a pain, would it be hard to show the first one as opened? and maybe we can wrap accordionContent in a div wrapper so i can style?

Comment: No worries. You could just trigger a click event via jQuery for the first item. Put this code here after the jQuery click event: $('.accordion h6').first().trigger('click');

Comment: Ahh yea that done the trick :) ill try and work out wrapping the html inbetween each h6 with a wrapper...  haha